# Variable in JSP is not increasing

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, increment

I have a JSP page with a form which calls the same page after the submit button is pressed. In the page I define a variable `x`, initially with the value of 1 and hence it fetches the data from DB corresponding to 1. Now when submit is pressed the value of x increases to 2 and the data should be fetched from DB corresponding to the new value. My problem is that the value increases but data is not fetched.Please tell me why?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<jsp:useBean id="Student" scope="session" class="StudentBean.StudentLoginBean"></jsp:useBean>
<%int x=1; %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>welcome <jsp:getProperty property="login" name="Student" />
</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OnTest";
    Connection con=null;
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(URL,"root","root");
    PreparedStatement stat=con.prepareStatement("select * from questions where qnNo="+x);
    x+=1;
    ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) {
        out.println(x);
        out.println(rs.getString(1));%>
        <form action="sucess.jsp">
        <br><input type ="radio" name ="answer" value="a">
        <%
        out.println(rs.getString(2));%>
                <input type ="radio" name ="answer" value="b">

        <%
        out.println(rs.getString(3));%>
                <input type ="radio" name ="answer" value="a">
        <%
        out.println(rs.getString(4));%>
                <input type ="radio" name ="answer" value="a">
        <%
        out.println(rs.getString(5));%>     
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">      
        </form>

        <%


        //System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
        //System.out.println("    "+rs.getString("password"));
        //v.addElement(rs.getString("name"));
        //v.addElement(rs.getString("name"));
    }
    if(!con.isClosed()) {
        out.println("success");
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        out.println(e);
        }
        %>
<h1><h1><h1>i am inside sucess</h1></h1></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this code - `<%int x=1; %>` to this `<%!int x=1; %>`.

Problem is : your `x` declaration is at local scope, which re-initializes for every call to .jsp (jsp_servlet).

by using `<%! ... %>` your `x` can be defined globlally.

Answer (score 0):

Would be a good thing if you separe logic from view.

Anyway after pressing submit it will reload the page, setting the x variable again at 1.

A solution could be to send the x parameter with the post data and increment it then.

```
<input type="text" name="x" value="${x}" /> <!-- If you're using EL -->

<input type="text" name="x" value="<%=x%>" />
```

And

```
<%
    int x = request.getParameter("x");
    if(x == null){
       x = 1;
    }
%>
```

By separate logic from view i mean that you should use Servlets, you will find a lot of documentation online :)

Comment: please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Edited the answer. Something like that should work, I haven't tested so i am not sure it would run without any error

Answer (score 0):

```
while(rs.next())
{
    out.println(x);
    <form action="sucess.jsp">

    out.println(rs.getString(1));%>
    <br><input type ="radio" name ="answer" value="a">
    <%
    out.println(rs.getString(2));%>
            <input type ="radio" name ="answer" value="b">

    <%
    out.println(rs.getString(3));%>
            <input type ="radio" name ="answer" value="c">
    <%
    out.println(rs.getString(4));%>
            <input type ="radio" name ="answer" value="d">
    <%
    out.println(rs.getString(5));%>     
            <input type ="radio" name ="answer" value="e">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">      
    </form>

    <%


    //System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
    //System.out.println("    "+rs.getString("password"));
    //v.addElement(rs.getString("name"));
    //v.addElement(rs.getString("name"));
}
```

Change these values and you will get the solution. Actually, you were not doing the first inside the Form method so it was behaving differently.